# WPF String Length Converter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ivalueconverter, string-length

I am using a converter to check if a String length is bigger then 0 or not.
If it's bigger i return true else false.

Everything is working fine. But i was wondering if this is the correct way of a converter?

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool error = false;
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                error = true;
            }
            else
            {
                error = false;
            }
        }
        return error;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNullConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
```

Comment: `return (value != null && value.ToString().Length > 0);`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. The code could be shorter, but other than that, it's fine.

Answer (score 6):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string str = value as string;
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way of using a converter, yes. But I'd probably use something like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (value != null && value.ToString().Length > 0);
}
```

**Edit**:

Based on other replies you could also use the following approach:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);
}
```

This will do it if you do not want non-string objects to return `true`

Comment: +1 for a nice succinct solution.  But would you call this converter `IsNullConverter`?

Comment: @Adam Mihalcin: I'd rather have it called `StringLengthToBoolConverter`. This way everyone knows at first sight what this is for and what it does. The `IsNullConverter` comes from the initial post and I've just copied it :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem with all other solutions is that they are calling `ToString()` which all objects support. However I believe he/she doesn't want non-string objects to return true. If this is the case, then this will do it:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
{ 
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);
} 

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
{ 
    throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNullConverter can only be used OneWay."); 
}
```

Comment: THanks for all the answers! Well the name IsNullConverter is because first it was a IsNullConverter but that didn't work, so i changed the code but didn't change the name xD

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string));
}
```